# Convert Python To Variable Assignment

Tags: python

I want to take a string with a variable and a value, and use it as an actual value. For example with the string:

```
“X = 5”
```

I want to make `X = 5`

I tried using:

```
Eval(“x = 5”)
```

But didn’t really expect it to work. How do I do this properly?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Basically anyone who wants to do this has [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040), and usually want the solution to [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/364696)

Comment: @ShadowRanger There are some use cases for this.  For example, a code preprocessor that uses `eval` to evaluate a python expression and generate a line of code that is a symbol.  But that's an esoteric case and not hinted at by OP.  In general, most of the time it is an XY.

Answer (score 1):

For local variables within a function, you can't do this in any reasonable way. At global scope, `eval(compile('X=5','','single'))` (`'single'` could be changed to `'exec'` to make it work on any amount of code, `'single'` limits it to a single statement) works as expected, as does `exec('X=5')`. But that's because global scope is based on a mutable `dict` under the hood. Within a function, the set of available variables is determined at compile time, you can't create true new locals dynamically.

Even when the local already exists, you can't modify it in a straightforward way. For example:

```
def foo(statement):
    x = 1
    eval(compile(statement, '', 'single'))  # Or eval(statement)
    print(x)
```

The result of the `print` will remain `1`, even if you pass `foo('x = 5')`, because all `eval`/`exec` can do is mutate the result of `locals()`, which, within a function, is a shallow-copy of the local state, and mutations to it do not affect the actual locals.

You *can* create a temporary `dict` to receive any variable the statement creates, then access them through that `dict`. For example:

```
def foo(statement):
    scope = {'x': 1}
    eval(compile(statement, '', 'single'), globals(), scope)  # Or eval(statement, globals(), scope)
    print(scope['x'])
```

*would* see the effects of `foo('x = 5')`, because it would be using a mutable `dict` that could be inspected to see the changes made to the scope by the statement.

Comment: Well explained, but then, to read the data into a dict (which is BTW more reasonable than storing into an unused variable anyway), it would be much better to just `split('=', 1)`, then `strip` the results, and finally update the target dict, than to `eval` arbitrary input.

Comment: @zvone: Agreed. If the string comes from known safe sources, and is too variable for simple parsing as in this case, `eval`/`exec` can make sense. But yeah, as I mentioned in the comment on the question, this is usually an XY problem that shouldn't be solved this way at all.

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is exec:

```
exec("x = 5")
```

Comment: This is fine in global scope, but won't do anything useful within a function.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes as you wrote in your dissertation on the topic in your answer.